# wifi driver kernel conflict in 23.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom, 23.04

Thanks. Ran the blacklist command in your instructions and got:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/modprobe.d/.b43.conf.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Tue Apr 25 11:11:48 2023
         file name: /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
          modified: YES
         user name: root   host name: pj-iMacUbuntu
        process ID: 10711
While opening file "/etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf"
      CANNOT BE FOUND
(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/modprobe.d/.b43.conf.swp
"
    to avoid this message.

"/etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf" [New File]
```

Located swap files.

```
Swap files found:
   Using specified name:
1.    .b43.conf.swo
          owned by: root   dated: Wed Apr 26 09:44:11 2023
         [cannot be opened]
2.    .b43.conf.swp
          owned by: root   dated: Tue Apr 25 11:11:48 2023
         [cannot be opened]
   In directory ~/tmp:
      -- none --
   In directory /var/tmp:
      -- none --
   In directory /tmp:
      -- none --

Enter number of swap file to use (0 to quit): 2
E306: Cannot open /etc/modprobe.d/.b43.conf.swp
```

Stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

updated kernel to latest stable version using this article:
https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu
wifi working now